# Function that I can use to remove a single page from a PDF using iText

Tags: java, pdf, itext

Similar: [How can I remove blank page from PDF in iText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2464166/how-can-i-remove-blank-page-from-pdf-in-itext)

I'm trying to make a generic function that can delete a page from a PDF using iText 5.5.x.

I wrote a function and it usually works ok. But I've gotten complaints from users that once and a while the function botches the PDF completely.

Any ideas what is wrong with my code to make it flakey?

```
public static void removePageFromPDF(File thePDFFile, int pageIndexNotZeroBased) throws InterruptedException, Exception {       
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(thePDFFile.getAbsolutePath());
        File tmpNewFile = File.createTempFile("pdfRemoveFile", "pdfouttemp.pdf");
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(tmpNewFile);
        com.itextpdf.text.Document d = new com.itextpdf.text.Document();
        PdfCopy copy = new PdfCopy(d, fos);
        d.open();
        for (int i = 1; i <= reader.getNumberOfPages(); ++i) {
            if (i != pageIndexNotZeroBased) {
                copy.addPage(copy.getImportedPage(reader, i));
            }
        }
        copy.freeReader(reader);
        reader.close();
        d.close();
        fos.close();
        FileUtils.copyFile(tmpNewFile, thePDFFile);
        tmpNewFile.delete();
    }
```

Comment: You copy the original file page by page dropping all interactive and document level content. Consider using a `PdfStamper` and selecting the pages you want to keep.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please read [chapter 6](http://manning.com/lowagie2/samplechapter6.pdf) of my book. You'll see that there are two method to select pages, one using `PdfCopy` and one using `PdfStamper`. The method using `PdfStamper` is much simpler than what you have, and it's more reliable too:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
reader.selectPages("!2");
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));
stamper.close();
```