# Find out a pdf is blank or not using iText java API

Tags: java, pdf

I am using iText java API for reading a pdf file.

Is it possible to find whether the pdf is contentless using same API?

I wish to write a method which reads a pdf from a specific location and returns whether a pdf is blank or not?

Comment: [This blog post](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-detect-and-remove-blank-page-in-pdf.html) looks promising.  Have you tried anything yet so we know how far your code is coming along?

Comment: I think you can go through this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2464166/how-can-i-remove-blank-page-from-pdf-in-itext

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: I haven't tried a code yet. Also, I find that the API doesn't have a predefined method. Can you help me write that method?

Comment: What do you mean by blank ? A single blank page? No page at all?

Comment: @KrutiPatel: Thanks!! This seems to be valuable

Comment: @HimanshuTyagi: A single blank page

Comment: @Shuja Is a page blank which has text in white on white blank? Or one which has text which then is covered by a white rectangle? Or which has off-screen contents? All those samples appear blank in print but are not contentless.